# 2 different projects for same app, upload issue (An app with identifier is not available)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect

I got a project that some developers were previously working on. We have 2 separated projects for same app: currently published app is first one, app we are upgrading and fixing is the other one. Now we decided to publish latest project but we cannot submit archive update to iTunes Connect.
We are using same profiles and everything, same bundle ID and we have increased version number and build. Also there is no issue under "Team" in targets General settings. Project builds and archives without a problem but after clicking on "Upload to App Store", we get an error:

> An App ID with Identifier is not available. Please enter a different string.

Recently we did an update to old version and it worked fine, but new one does not work.
I do not have a clue why there are two separate projects so please do not ask questions to this topic, I am just trying to solve this problem out.

Will provide any info if you need. Thank you for your help in advance.